# App is Force closing without Force Close Message

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, forceclose

I'm a little bit confused....

I have the following method and my App is closing without a Force close dialog. And I don't know why. I think it should be all fine...
I can't give more information. If you want more, please ask me.

```
public void findCC3000(View view) {
        new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {
            private ProgressDialog dialog;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMax(64516);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                this.dialog.setProgress(0);
                this.dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                int port = Integer.valueOf(((EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText_port)).getText().toString());
                String  ip = ((EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.editText_ip)).getText().toString();
                try {
                    out("try to connect");
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printWriter.println("");



                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String fromServer;

                    out("listen for message");



                while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) { //CRASH-------------------------------------------------------
                    out(fromServer);
                    if (fromServer.equals("Connected to CC3000")) {
                        out("CC3000 found! : " + ip);
                        //startListenThread();
                        out("Started Lissten thread " );
                        findViewById(R.id.button_connect).setEnabled(false);
                        findViewById(R.id.joystickView_geschwindigkeit).setEnabled(true);
                        findViewById(R.id.joystickView_lenkung).setEnabled(true);
                        return ip;
                    }
                }



                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    out(e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    out(e.getMessage());
                }

                return "";
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (result.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CC3000 not found! :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CC3000 found! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ip = result;
            }
        }.execute("192.168.");
    }
```

But I know the place.
So the important part is (the readLine()):

```
while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) { //CRASH-------------------------------------------------------
                        out(fromServer);
                        if (fromServer.equals("Connected to CC3000")) {
                            out("CC3000 found! : " + ip);
                            //startListenThread();
                            out("Started Lissten thread " );
                            findViewById(R.id.button_connect).setEnabled(false);
                            findViewById(R.id.joystickView_geschwindigkeit).setEnabled(true);
                            findViewById(R.id.joystickView_lenkung).setEnabled(true);
                            return ip;
                        }
                    }
```

This is my Logcat:

> 06-06 16:12:16.494  20152-20166/de.mayerhofersimon.cc3000.main
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4155dce0)

Hope you can help.

regards

Comment: Look in your unfiltered logcat-  I suspect you'll find a native code crash and stack dump there.

Comment: only the UI Thread should touch the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the UI Thread can touch the UI. You can take a look the implementation of  `setEnabled`

```
4586     public void More ...setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
4587         if (enabled == isEnabled()) return;
4588 
4589         setFlags(enabled ? ENABLED : DISABLED, ENABLED_MASK);
4590 
4591         /*
4592          * The View most likely has to change its appearance, so refresh
4593          * the drawable state.
4594          */
4595         refreshDrawableState();
4596 
4597         // Invalidate too, since the default behavior for views is to be
4598         // be drawn at 50% alpha rather than to change the drawable.
4599         invalidate(true);
4600     }
```